# Unable to create temporary file; errno: 2 while Running Mysql server on Windows

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to run Mysql server 8.0.19 on my Windows machine. I am using Mysql installer to start the mysql server. But I get the below error. I uninstalled and installed many times. I tried a lot but unable to solve my issue. can someone please help me?

> C:>mysqld --initialize --console
>
> 2020-06-17T20:40:26.353489Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.19) initializing of server in progress as process 9044
> 2020-06-17T20:40:26.398191Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012576] [InnoDB] Unable to create temporary file; errno: 2
>
> 2020-06-17T20:40:26.400178Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012929] [InnoDB] InnoDB
> Database creation was aborted with error Generic error. You may need to delete the ibdata1 file before trying to start up again.
>
> 2020-06-17T20:40:26.403787Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data
> Dictionary initialization failed.
>
> 2020-06-17T20:40:26.405387Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\ is unusable. You can > remove all files that the server added to it.
>
> 2020-06-17T20:40:26.408100Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
>
> 2020-06-17T20:40:26.409738Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.19)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.